# What does dsfg as a part of package names mean?

Tags: package-management, debian

I know the general format for package names in Debian and Ubuntu. Some packages have additions to the standard numbering scheme with obvious meaning like `svn20090426` etc. But also quite a few packages have **dsfg** in their name (e.g. `2:1.0~rc4~try1.dsfg1-1ubuntu1`) – what does that mean?

Is it just a typo of the *Debian Free Software Guidelines* (DFSG)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Free_Software_Guidelines

A package with 'dfsg'/'dsfg' suffix is one that has been stripped of any files 
that doesn't follow the Debian Free Software Guidelines.

(From Debian mailing list: http://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/2010/08/msg00169.html)

Comment: So is *dsfg* indeed a typo and should be *dfsg*?

Comment: I see three source packages with that typo indeed...

Comment: Yes, I bet it's a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dsfg is a "typo" I think it's more of a ACRONYM for Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG). Just my two cents.

Comment: Typo means it is misspelled. It was said in the other answer that it is an acronym but with a typo. Notice that the `s` and `f` are mixed up.