# What do all these fields really mean in an Ubuntu package version?

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging, versions

For example, in Ubuntu 14.04, `dpkg -l bind9` outputs:

```
||/ Name            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============-============================-================================================
ii  bind9           1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.15     amd64                        Internet Domain Name Server
```

The version, `1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.15`, looks like it is comprised of many pieces of information. How many sections are there in this `Version` field, and what are the meanings of them?

From some vague webpage, some conclusions which also needed further confirmation:

- `1` in `1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.15` - **epoch**
- `9.9.5.dfsg` - **upstream-version**,
- `dfsg` in `9.9.5.dfsg`--- see [What does dsfg as a part of package names mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11592/what-does-dsfg-as-a-part-of-package-names-mean)
- `3ubuntu0.15` - **debian-revision**
- `3` in `3ubuntu0.15` - see [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/deb-version.5.html) #debian-revision (thanks to @Rinzwind)

To be solved:

- `ubuntu0.15` in `3ubuntu0.15`?
- `0.15` in `3ubuntu0.15`?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/deb-version.5.html